# Call a stored procedure with a function returned value parameter ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have this UDF that takes some parameters collected from an GUI.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnCreateAppoitmentXML] (@PacientID int
, @DataProgramare datetime2(7)
, @PacientNume varchar(50)
, @PacientEmail varchar(100)
, @PacientTelefon varchar(50)
, @PacientSimptome varchar(100))
RETURNS xml

AS
BEGIN


  RETURN (SELECT (SELECT
      @PacientId AS PacientId,
      @DataProgramare AS DataProgramare,
      @PacientNume AS PacientNume,
      @PacientEmail AS PacientEmail,
      @PacientTelefon AS PacientTelefon,
      @PacientSimptome AS PacientSimptome
    FOR
    xml PATH ('PacientDate'),
    TYPE)
  FOR xml PATH (''),
  ROOT ('root'))
END
```

From MVC 5 project I need to call below SP that takes an XML as parameter(the return type of the function)

```
@xmldoc xml
AS
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
    BEGIN TRY
      INSERT INTO [dbo].[ProgramareMF] (PacientID, DataProgramare, PacientNume, PacientEmail, PacientTelefon, PacientSimptome)
        (SELECT
          xmldoc.i.value('./PacientId[1]', 'int'),
          xmldoc.i.value('./DataProgramare[1]', 'datetime2(7)'),
          xmldoc.i.value('./PacientNume[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
          xmldoc.i.value('./PacientEmail[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
          xmldoc.i.value('./PacientTelefon[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
          xmldoc.i.value('./PacientSimptome[1]', 'varchar(100)')
        FROM @xmldoc.nodes('/root/PacientDate') AS xmldoc (i))
    COMMIT TRAN;
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
      ROLLBACK TRAN;
    THROW;
  END CATCH;
END
```

My first question is can I ran a SP in .NET and supply it with UDF return value as a parameter. If this is possible should I store the return value of the function into a variable, or directly supply the SP with the UDF as a parameter???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send the udf. It's sql, not c#.
But you can send the name of the udf and the parameters it should get and run it directly from the stored procedure.
In this case, however, you can skip the udf all together and just send the parameters to the stored procedure.

Comment: I need to use XML , these are the specs... will do some brain storming and come with some info, thanks